# Configure RavenDb to run on another port

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

I'm using the **`RavenDB-Build-2380`** which is running on **default port 8080**.  Hence it is using

```
http://localhost:8080/raven/studio.html#/databases?database=Test
```

How to configure RavenDb to run on another port?

I tried changing the following in **Raven.Server.exe.config** file, yet not working

```
<add key="Raven/Port" value="*"/>
```

Kindly share your suggestions on this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `<add key="Raven/Port" value="88"/>` should work. You will need to quit Raven.Server and start it again.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the port the number here

```
<add key="Raven/Port" value="5050"/>
```

A restart of Raver.Server is required.

> **Command:** Raven.Server.exe /restart

In latest build of **Raven 2666**, they brought the new feature of **windows installer**.  While installing, it popup a window where the **port configuration** quite easy.